# рамка с треугольником

Tags: css, css3

Насколько реально сделать вот такую рамку на css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где треугольник это часть картинки и картинка может быть любой другой т.е. я хочу сказать, что добавить такой треугольник не подойдет здесь

```
border: 20px solid transparent; 
border-left: 20px solid green; 
border-top: 20px solid green;
```

В треугольнике часть картинки находится а не просто цвет. Вообщем как сделать такую рамку на css?

Comment: А border сам у данного тултипа будет всегда одного цвета или тоже разного?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну цвет border'а всегда одного цвета

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подсмотрев одну идею в интернете, я немного попробовал помудрил и получилось вот что:

html:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrap">
<div class="tooltip-content">
    <img src='http://www.lolhome.ru/uploads/posts/2012-09/1347844282_foto-prikoly-11.jpg'>
</div>

<div class='tooltip-triangle'>
    <div class='tooltip-triangle-wrap top-triangle'>
        <img src='http://www.lolhome.ru/uploads/posts/2012-09/1347844282_foto-prikoly-11.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='tooltip-triangle-wrap'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* 
photo original width: 604px;
photo original height: 592px;
*/
.tooltip-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
}

.tooltip-content {
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tooltip-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 156px;
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
    bottom: -153px;
    left: 78px;
}

.tooltip-triangle-wrap {    
    width: 604px;
    height: 592px;
}

.tooltip-triangle-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;  

  transform: skewX(-55.98deg); 
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

.tooltip-triangle-wrap:first-child {
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -234px;
    left: -78px;
}

.tooltip-triangle-wrap:last-child {
  right: -.25em;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.tooltip-triangle-wrap img, .tooltip-triangle-wrap:after {
  transform: skewX(55.98deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
```

**[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/991d9w5u/)**

Вам придется немного адаптировать величины ширины высоты и позиций для себя.

По идее, немного поманипулировав шириной и высотой тултипа, и треугольника, а также расположением треугольника и картинки внутри как вам надо - можно будет просто скриптом менять картинки как вам надо.

Если хотите, то можете попробовать оттолкнуться от этого примера: **[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/8edk7fgz/)**

Comment: Мне кажется идеально было бы если задача решена с одной картинкой. С двумя картинками не комильфо. Но всё равно спасибо Вам! Вы показали путь к истине!

Comment: @bemulima К сожалению, в подобных задачах, когда нужно отобразить  часть одного и того же изображения по сути в разных контентах, то одной картинкой не обойтись